# UITableView Using two arrays

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to load values from two Arrays into my UITableView which is causing `Array index out of range` Error.

1.`categories` array contains 60 elements, I'm using this array to set    `cell.textLabel.text`

2.`colorsArray` array contains 5 UIColor elements, I'm using this to set `cell.backgroundColor`

I'm trying to cycle through these 5 colors repetitively.

CODE:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellID = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = category.books[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

`fatal error: Array index out of range`

I think I need to make the colorsArray to have 60 elements. Is there a way in code to do that?

i tried

```
var categories = category.count
     for (i=0;i<categories;i++) {
        colorArray.append(colorArray[i])
}
```

Doing that makes the Error go away temporarily. But as soon as I scroll down in the TableView, app crashes again.

`fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb)`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The index path will be 59 at some time and the colorsArray has only 5 elements.You can call another function from tableView

Comment: Hi. I want to my `UITableCell` to have different colors based on the value of UIColor at the index.

Comment: @Statik: learn about moldulo operation

Comment: Never going to forget it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellID = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = category.books[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.row % 5]
        return cell
}
```

Comment: Does exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Since a lack of explanation was provided in the answer, the added `%5` is used to get the remained of X devided by 5. This will make sure that the highest count is 5 and thus the array won’t get out of bounds.

Comment: @Statik, so you wanted your table view cell's color to cycle through 5 different colors repeatedly? Can you edit your question to make that clear?

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is that you'd like a repeating sequence of background colors for each cell as you add a row to your table view, you can use the remainder operator (%) to keep the index into your colorArray within its bounds:

`cell.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.row % 5]`